# How to get weekly data from beginning of month using date_range of Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I want to divide the date range starting from 1st July to 1st August, in weekly basis. But I want it to start from 1st day of the month.

I am using `pd.date_range('2015-07-01', '2015-08-01', freq='W' )`

But I am getting

`DatetimeIndex(['2015-07-05', '2015-07-12', '2015-07-19', '2015-07-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-SUN')`

I want this to be done from `2015-07-01`. I know I can use `timedelta` or find the start day of the month and use `W-WED`. But is there any other shortcut to do the same using `date_range` of `pandas`?

I have checked http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases, but could not come up with anything useful.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the frequency of 7 days instead of a week, so that you will start at the first day of the month rather than the first day of the week

```
pd.date_range('2015-07-01', '2015-08-01', freq='7d')
```

**EDIT**

To clarify, it is not strictly the first day of the month, but the first day you provide. But in your example those two are the same